# URL Rewriting is not working after migrating to Apache 2.4 from Apache 2,2

Tags: url-rewriting, cognos, apache2.4, cognos-10, apache2.2

All systems are configured in domain and application login is done through SSO (LDAP).

Previously it was configured on Apache 2.2 and it was working fine.
After migrating to Apache 2.4, URL rewriting is not working as expected.

URL rewrite with Apache 2.2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "rules.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5

CustomLog "E:/Program Files/Apache2/conf/headertrack.log" "S %t %{REMOTE_USER}i %{REMOTE_UID}i %h %U"

RewriteRule ^/$ /cognos [L,R=301]
```

URL rewrite with Apache 2.4

```
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace5

CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/conf/headertrack.log" "S %t %{REMOTE_USER}i %{REMOTE_UID}i %h %U"

RewriteRule ^/$ /cognos
```

'headertrack.log' file having the logs in same format and it is also printing username as well.

Can you please provide the correct URL rewrite rule for Apache 2.2

Let me know if nay other details are required.

Answer (score 0):

There are sample templates provided by the CA gateway install:

You can use one of the sample configuration files that are provided with IBM Cognos Analytics. The sample files are in gateway_component_install_location/cgi-bin/templates where gateway_component_install_location is the directory where the gateway component is installed. The following table describes the sample files. Choose the file for your environment:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/t_config_ish_with_ssl.html

Comment: I'm using Cognos 10.2.2 and given documentation link is for Cognos Analytics 11.

I think only - `RewriteRule ^/$ /cognos` require changes.